# Is it possible to install MS Office on the virtual window using CDs?

Tags: windows-7, linux, microsoft-office

I am new to Redhat linux.  I need to run a virtual copy of Windows 7 and need to use MS Office.  I am not sure how to get MS Office installed in the virtual Windows 7 using the CDs.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox to run Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

In the settings for each virtual image, there are options what to use for an optical drive. You can toggle this to use either a virtual CD image or a physical optical drive from the host machine (your Linux OS). Each Virtual program manager is slightly different, but the idea is the same. Here what the setting looks like for VirtualBox running on windows, where clicking the CD icon shows the popup to choose between virtual and physical drives. For the virtual drive option, it allows you to pick ISO file of a CD/DVD image.
[image: Sample optical drive settings for VirtualBox.]

Comment: Nice! That is a better option. I'll delete my answer as this is the easiest approach.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 We support multiple options here, no need to get rid of a decent answer just because there is a "better" one available. Choosing the best options is what the voting options are for.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

If you're using `Microsoft Office 2010` you could download the executable (for your version) directly onto the Virtual Machine from [My Digital River](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-office-2010-official-direct-download-links/) and use your valid CD key when installing.

Just make sure you don't use the CD key on multiple VM's, but I'm sure you know that.

**Approach 2:**

An alternative to the above would be to create an image (.iso) from the CD and add it to the Windows 7 VM Storage Tree (Located under Storage - Settings). I'm assuming you're using VirtualBox.